# Using Doc2Vec to find salience score for resumes based on job description

Tags: nlp, gensim, doc2vec, information-extraction

Here is my use case:

HR department provide `job description`(free text) and set of `resumes`(plain text), and the ask is to come up with salience score based on job description relevance.

The `job description` consists of skills required and minimum qualification. I was considering **Doc2Vec** but bit confused **how should I train the model**?

1. If I collate all job descriptions, and create corpus, querying profile text will give incorrect results.
2. Moreover, job requisitions are transient in nature and a profile might match with a expired requisition.

Since each job description is exclusive, shall I create a trained model for each job? Or if there's any better framework, please advise.

Please see the code below:

```
'
import os
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities

path = <working_dir>

os.chdir(path)

with open('Dir int Strategy.txt') as f:
    job_desc_text = f.read()

with open('Jeannine.txt') as f:
    candidate1_text = f.read()

with open('Penny.txt') as t:
    candidate2_text = t.read()

with open('Omar.txt') as z:
    candidate3_text = z.read()


with open('Kyle.txt') as p:
    candidate4_text = p.read()

documents = [candidate1_text, candidate2_text, candidate3_text,candidate4_text]   
stoplist = set('for a of the and to in'.split())   
documents_split_texts = [[word for word in document.lower().split() if  word not in stoplist]
    for document in documents]   
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(documents_split_texts)   
dictionary.save('/tmp/deerwester.dict')        

corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in documents_split_texts]   
corpora.MmCorpus.serialize('/tmp/deerwester.mm', corpus)     

tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus)      

query_vector = job_desc_text    
query_vector = dictionary.doc2bow(query_vector.lower().split())

index = similarities.SparseMatrixSimilarity(tfidf[corpus], num_features=699)     

sims = index[tfidf[query_vector]]            
'
```

Comment: Are the resumes provided by HR positive examples of people who've filled the job well in the past, or all candidates?

Comment: Yes, there is a mixed bag of candidates who were selected and rejected (along with reasons)

Answer (score 1):

Published results using the `Doc2Vec` algorithm ('Paragraph Vector') tend to include tens-of-thousands to millions of distinct documents – so you'll likely want or need to combine all your documents together to make one stronger model, rather than make a model-per-job.

It's good that you have both positive examples, of resumes that fit a job, and negative examples. (It might be ever better if you had resume

A possible 1st approach would be to combine all job-descriptions and available-resumes into one corpus, and train a `Doc2Vec` model on that. It may already then be the case that resume doc-vectors are "close" (via the usual cosine-similarity) to job-description doc-vectors for which that candidate is appropriate. You could score this simple approach based on how well "good" resumes are closer than "bad" (or "other-job-entirely") resumes. You could tune multiple aspects of this baseline by varying your preprocessing/parameters (like model modes, vector-size, etc) to see how much the score can be helped.

But, it's likely that these 'raw' distances will miss subtleties that other methods could find, especially given that the use of language may vary a lot between job-descriptions and resumes (so mere document-similarity doesn't indicate a good match), and that you have both positive and negative examples.

Even without considering the job-descriptions at all, if you have a manageable number of unique jobs and they don't change very much, you could try training a binary-classifier (good-or-not), or a regressor (especially if your 'goodness' data has multiple levels from 'awful' to 'great'), for each individual job-opening. You'd again score this by how well it picks known-good over known-bad resumes, and as possible tune the preprocessing/Doc2Vec-parameters/classifier-parameters to improve the score.

Considering the job-descriptions, you could try training a single overall binary-classifier or regressor, that takes as input both the job-description doc-vector and the resume doc-vector (as a single concatenated larger vector), and reports some overall match – and again score & optimize it against the other methods.

Comment: Thanks gojomo. I'll try the second option of creating vectors and using in a regressor.

Comment: There is one thing I have observed when creating vector and finding MatrixSimilarities(without applying regressor). If I have a vector of 10 resume documents and each have a score against a job description query vector. If I add few more document to the existing resume vector, the score of each documents change.

E.g. Resume 1 has .03, Resume 2 has .97 and Resume 3 has .45 scores. If I add Resume 4, the score of each resume changes. Does the MatrixSimilarity scores relatively and not on individual document content? I am creating vector using LSI model.

Comment: I'm sorry, without seeing code I'm not sure what you mean by "add a few more document to the existing resume vector". And, the pairwise cosine-similarity between 2 vectors shouldn't be affected by other comparisons, unless you're somehow recalculating the vectors or getting their order mixed-up. And for all these techniques, you won't want to be often recalculating vectors on small slightly-different corpuses: they all work better with one large corpus.

Comment: Apologies for late reply. I have added the code in the original post. I have created one vector of all the candidate profile's texts and the other (query vector) is of job description.

Comment: Does that code give useful results? It's not using `Doc2Vec'. Also still unclear what "add a few more document to the existing resume vector" meant, and I don't see in the code where scores change. (But note: if using TF/IDF analysis, any chances to the overall frequencies of words will change their weights, so in that case a pair of documents A & B in one TFIDF model may have one similarity-value, while those same docs A & B in a different model, with different term frequencies in other documents, may get a different similarity-value.

Comment: Yes it gave useful results. Since I think I haven't train it, not sure how accurate it'll be always. What I meant with adding few more documents is if I run this program, it'll give score to all four documents. And now if I add another document to **documents** array, the score of all the previous four documents will change. And that I think you made it clear stating that it always re-calculate with changes in corpus.